# Vector Operation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Can any body help me explain Line 7 of this code. What does this line

```
temp(min(temp,[],2) >=1 & max(temp,[],2)<=N,:)
```

do in the code?

Line 7 of this code is throwing me off

```
 N=10;
 H=-1;
 J=0;
 for i=1:N
     for j=1:N
         temp=[i-1,j;i+1,j;i,j-1;i,j+1];
         ngh{i,j}=temp(min(temp,[],2) >=1 & max(temp,[],2)<=N,:);
     end
 end
```

Comment: With the indentation you had, it doesn't surprise me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line is selecting the rows of `temp` which have all values between `1` and `N`, and assigning that submatrix to `ngh{i,j}`.

Note that

- `min(...,[],2)` or `max(...,[],2)` gives the minimum or maximum of each row;
- The logical comparison with `1` or `N` and the `&` operation result in a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) vector, which is used to address the desired rows of `temp` (and all columns).